# Cypress how to get all children element from the parent element but no grand children

Tags: cypress

Cypress how to get all children element from the parent element but not grand children
getting those two button directly from the body but not the sub/grand child(ren) from the form

For example

```
<body>
 <button></button>
 .
 .
 .
 <button></button>
 <form>
   <button></button>
   .
   .
   .
 </form>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean? HTML elements are trees, if you select all children of `body`, you get three elements, two of which with an empty child list, and one with a non-empty child list. There is no such thing as "the form, without the button in it", because that's not what's on the page, and would be a different element.

Comment: Hi Mike:  If I use
cy.get('body').find('button'), it will return 3 "button" elements.  I wanted to exclude the one inside the form.
I think Alapan did answer it.  But I am looking for little bit more than just "children", it is like specific element like this example "button"

Comment: Ah, in that case the question is more "what qualifies one button over another", because if you just ask for "all buttons" then computers and humans alike won't know why `div button` is okay, but `div form button` isn't. Do have have a stricter description of which elements should qualify, and which shouldn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be as simple as specifying the **direct descendants only** with `parent > child` selector

Please try this

```js
cy.get('body > button')
  .its('length')
  .should('eq', 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be specific about the children you are looking for,

```js
cy.get('body').children('button')
```

for instance,

```html
<body>
  <button>C1</button>
  <button>C2</button>
  <div>D</div>
  <form>
    <button>GC</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

```js
cy.get('body').children('button')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('eq', 'C1C2')
```

---

**Checking immediate parent**

I was also looking for a way to specify the parent is `<body>`.

There's no native Cypress way, but you can add a jQuery expression

```js
Cypress.$.expr[":"].parentIs = function(el, idx, selector) {
  return Cypress.$(el).parent().is(selector[selector.length - 1]);
}

cy.get('button')
  .filter(':parentIs(body)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a combination of `children()` and `not` to get the two children instead of three.

```js
cy.get('body').children('button').not('form')
```

[image: Test runner screenshot]

In case you want to get specific children element you can use the `.eq()` command:

```js
cy.get('body').children('button').eq(0) //yields first button
cy.get('body').children('button').eq(1) //yields second button
```

You can also use `filter()` if your buttons have unique texts. This in my opinion is a much cleaner way-

```js
cy.get('body').find('button').filter(':contains("buttontText")')
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am lookgin for specific element like in this example "button".  There will be more DOM elements inside body
cy.get('body').find('button').not('form')  will still return all 3 button elements.